# How to center floating in enumerate environment?

Tags: floats, enumerate

I would place the floating center, while it is left.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[charter,uppercase = upright]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{float}
\def\a{blabla blabla blabla blabla  blabla blabla }
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{USenglish}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \a
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{mplibcode}
 beginfig(1);
 u:=1cm;
 defaultscale := 0.9;
 z0=(0,0);
 z1=(4u,0);
 z2=(6u,3u);
 z3=(2u,3u);
 z4=whatever[z0,z2]=whatever[z1,z3];
 path p ;
 p=z0--z3;
 draw z0--z1--z2--z3--cycle;
 draw z1--z3;
 draw z2--z0;
 label.lrt("B",z1);
 label.urt("C",z2);
 label.ulft("D",z3);
 label.llft("A",z0);
 label.top("E",z4 shifted(0,0.1u));
 draw (1u,0) withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor red;      
 draw point (1/3)*length(p) of p withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor red;
 label.bot(btex $\color{red}I$ etex,(1u,0));
 label.lft(btex $\color{red}J$ etex,point (1/3)*length(p) of p);
 endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{figure}
\a
\begin{enumerate}
\item \a
\item \a
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a typical case in which you do **not** want to use a floating environment. I suggest you remove the `figure` and simply use `{\centering ... }` to center its contents. The absence of a figure environment doesn't prevent you from adding a caption: use `\captionof` from the `caption` package.

Comment: @Jubobs the use of `\captionof` requires a "container", typically a `minipage` (although a `center` environment could be another option).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Aren't braces enough of a container?

Comment: @Jubobs see remark on page 18 of the caption package documentation: "Since `\captionof` uses the option type internally, the same restrictions as for the type option apply here, so you should use both `\captionof` and `\captionof*` only inside boxes or environments, too." I wouln't know if using just a group is safe enough.

Comment: @Jubobs That would be a question for Axel. In any case, in this particular case, just using `\centering` (inside a group) is not enough to center the `mplibcode` environment.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for that. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For other contents, it would be enough to use `\centering`, but this has no effect on `mplibcode` since the contents of this environment is placed inside an `\hbox`; however, you can use `\hfill`s:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[charter,uppercase = upright]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{float}
\def\A{blabla blabla blabla blabla  blabla blabla }
\def\a{\A\A\A}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{USenglish}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \a
\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill\begin{mplibcode}
 beginfig(1);
 u:=1cm;
 defaultscale := 0.9;
 z0=(0,0);
 z1=(4u,0);
 z2=(6u,3u);
 z3=(2u,3u);
 z4=whatever[z0,z2]=whatever[z1,z3];
 path p ;
 p=z0--z3;
 draw z0--z1--z2--z3--cycle;
 draw z1--z3;
 draw z2--z0;
 label.lrt("B",z1);
 label.urt("C",z2);
 label.ulft("D",z3);
 label.llft("A",z0);
 label.top("E",z4 shifted(0,0.1u));
 draw (1u,0) withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor red;      
 draw point (1/3)*length(p) of p withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor red;
 label.bot(btex $\color{red}I$ etex,(1u,0));
 label.lft(btex $\color{red}J$ etex,point (1/3)*length(p) of p);
 endfig;
\end{mplibcode}\hfill\null
\end{figure}
\a
\begin{enumerate}
\item \a
\item \a
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you don't want the figure to float and you are already using `float`, I used the `H` placement specifier to suppress flotation. Another option would be to use a `minipage` instead of `figure` and provide a caption (if required) using `\captionof` from the `caption` or `capt-of` packages; in this case, however, you would still have to use `\hfill` to center the contents.

Comment: I would definitely avoid `figure`.

Answer (score 4):

The figure will centre if you use

```
\leavevmode\begin{mplibcode}
```

Probably the environment ought to supply the `\leavevmode` itself to match all other latex box constricts, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: With `\edef\mplibcode{\noexpand\leavevmode\unexpanded\expandafter{\mplibcode}}` one can avoid adding `\leavevmode` in front of each `\begin{mplibcode}`